# MathJax, how to change text size?

Tags: mathjax

I am using a library (https://github.com/kexanie/MathView) to easily use MathJax in my android app.

But some of the formulas are big enough to fit in the screen and go outside.

The library's MathView does not have provision to change the text's size.
And when I try to make it scrollable, the text becomes too big in size.

How do I change that and make the text smaller? Or any other alternative solutions?

Comment: You should show what you've tried. E.g., have you configured automatic line-breaking, cf. https://github.com/kexanie/MathView#configuration?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yes I tried, but I don't want to use line breaks, the formulas aren't looking great with multiple lines.

Comment: So you want to scale down the expression to fit the screen? That will require client-side JS to detect the available space. I don't know MathView or any Android restrictions but on here's an old example  https://codepen.io/pkra/pen/jqKzZr

Answer (score 3):

It seems impossible to determine the exact size of texts in math view.
The solution is some kind of approximate font sizes like small, big, bigger, ...

So, you could use these elements to make changes in your Math View text size:

```
\tiny
\Tiny
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

As a simple example; `\tiny LOVE` gives "LOVE" written with a font size of almost 6 and `\HUGE LOVE` gives "LOVE" written in a font size of almost 36.

Answer (score 3):

To change the font size globally, add this for v2:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  CommonHTML: {
    scale: 90
  },
  "HTML-CSS": {
    scale: 90
  },
  NativeMML: {
    scale: 90
  },
  SVG: {
    scale: 90
  },
  PreviewHTML: {
    scale: 90
  }
});
</script>
```

or this for v3 (before the polyfill):

```
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  chtml: {
    scale: 0.9
  },
  svg: {
    scale: 0.9
  }
};
</script>
```

Change `90` or `0.9` to your preferred setting.